# When i enter value into textbox and hit submit i want that value below the textbox using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

Welcome.jsp

This is my jsp page. When I enter a value into the textbox and hit enter I want the name displayed with the `<p>` tag. I am new to ajax. Please help me with this as well as can we send model to ajax ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
    <script>
            function ajaxCall()
            {
                //alert("in js");
                $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/welcomePage",
                            data: "name=" + $('#name').val(), 

                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                alert("success !"); 
                                $('#show').html(data);
                            },
                            error: function()
                            {
                                alert("Error");
                            }

                });
                return false;
            }
    </script>
<body>
    <h2 align="center">Welcome to Spring MVC</h2>

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="ajaxCall();"/>
    </form>

    <p>Your name is</p><div id="show"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

DemoController.java

```
package com.demo.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller 
public class DemoController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/welcomePage" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String showPage(
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
        {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            /*ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Welcome");
            model.addObject("name",name);
            System.out.println("Name is:"+name);*/
            return name;
        }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to prepend a '..' before the '/welcomePage' so if resolves to the root such as: '../welcomePage' or if you want the current directory and welcomePage is your jsp file use: 'welcomePage.jsp'

Comment: no my jsp file is Welcome.jsp. I will try ../welcomPage .

Comment: It does'nt work . I am getting a error alert when i press on submit button.

Comment: Also for using Jquery .ajax data is expected to be an object such as `data: { name:'name'}` fyi. Put three parameters in the error function and place a debugger statement to see what they are.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/DemoApplication/?name=hello this is what comes up in the url after i hit submit. It does not go to the welcomePage url

Comment: If you want it to go to your welcome page you need to include that in your url: `../folder/Welcome.jsp`

The url is the location of the file to be requested or the default `index` file if a folder is requested in the url.

Comment: I want it to hit the /welcomePage controller request mapping so that it can return the 'name' to the jsp page.

Comment: In that case specify the url of the welcomePage controller in the url parameter. Just remember '../' will start at the root directory and './' or no slash will start from the current directory your current page was loaded from.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **submit** type button in a form submits the form to it's **action** url, if no URL is specified, current URL is reloaded. When a form submits current page context (DOM, CSS, JS) is destroyed, in short nothing can be done with the current page when form is submitted.

All you need to do is stop form from submitting itself

To do that you can return false to it's **onsubmit** event, like below

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="ajaxCall();"/>
</form>
```

From the look of it, everything else is correct, so after you make this simple change it should work.

Comment: It still pops up the Error alert and nothing happens after that.

Comment: That means your AJAX call failed. Open the page in Chrome and open Developer tools (F12 windows), go to network tab. Now submit again, you'll be able to see the network request made by AJAX and the URL it's trying to call. Most likely URL is incorrect.

Comment: Its working. Thanks for the help. Can i also return a model from the controller in the same way ?

Comment: You mean you need model as JSON ? Yes you can do it with @ResponseBody, you'll have to provide a JSON provider like Jackson. See this link http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/json-response-with-responsebody_31.html